# How to test every requests exceptions

Tags: python, pytest

I created a class RequestBuilder that contains all the requests I do

```
class RequestBuilder():

        def get(self, url: str):
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=self._headers)
            response.raise_for_status()

            return response
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
            Logger.error("HTTP ERROR "+errh)
            raise 
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
            Logger.error("CONNECTION ERROR "+errc)
            raise
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
            Logger.error("HTTP TIMOUT "+errt)
            raise
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            Logger.error("REQUEST ERROR "+err)
            raise
```

I would like to do unit tests on it using the response module but the coverage can't get through the last 2 exceptions : Timeout and RequestException

```
@responses.activate 
def testRequestOK():
    responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://sample.com', json={'status':'ok'}, status=200)
    rb = RequestBuilder()
    resp = rb.get('http://sample.com')

    assert len(responses.calls) == 1

@responses.activate 
def testRequestBuilderHTTPERROR():
    responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://sample.com', json={'status':'no ok'}, status=501)

    rb = RequestBuilder() 
    with pytest.raises(BaseException):
        rb.get('http://sample.com')

@responses.activate 
def testRequestBuilderHTTPERROR2():
    responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://sample.com', json={'status':'no ok'}, status=403)

    rb = RequestBuilder() 
    with pytest.raises(Exception):
        rb.get('http://sample.com')
```

How can I simulate a Timeout and a requestException ?

Comment: Probably easiest to just mock request.get

Answer (score 1):

Solved with mocking the different exceptions :

```
from utils.requestBuilder import RequestBuilder
import responses

import requests

from requests import exceptions as request_exception
import pytest
import mock
def testGetExceptionTimeout():
    with mock.patch('requests.get', side_effect=request_exception.Timeout('Failed Request')) as mock_request_post:
        rb = RequestBuilder()
        with pytest.raises(Exception):
            rb.get('http://sample.com')

def testGetExceptionRequestException():
    with mock.patch('requests.get', side_effect=request_exception.RequestException('Failed Request')) as mock_request_post:
        rb = RequestBuilder()
        with pytest.raises(Exception):
            rb.get('http://sample.com')
```